Why does the encoding break when I receive an image file from the api router in nextjs
I use the page router of nextjs.
Instead of sending form data directly from the front end to the server, it is sent to the API router first and then to the server end from the API router.
But here
If you get the body through the api router and check it at the terminal, the file image encoding is broken. (like Ý\x1B +   G I\x14  "I \x12\x17 JD V֭      '3 pɷ ....)
Of course, we've solved it.
In formData, the image file was encoded into base64 and sent, and then converted from the API router to the buffer was solved
I still don't understand why the image file format is broken.
I would appreciate it if you could give me a general explanation of the server and why.
// src/pages/api/[...serverRequest].ts
 const base64Data = body[key].file.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
          const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');
          formData.append(key, buffer, { filename: body[key].fileName });

